# Faster to use MySQL's CURDATE() or PHP's date()?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it faster to use  the mysql query:

```
SELECT CURDATE() as today
```

or the PHP statement:

```
$curdate = date('Y-m-d');
```

Does the same answer apply to using `date()` VS MySQL's `NOW()` and `CURTIME()`?

Comment: i think first one is faster to insert on mysql and second one is best to show date on php page not to insert into db

Comment: Please give us more context - are you doing anything with this in the database, or in PHP? As it stands, it's impossible to decide.

Comment: Out of interest, are you trying to repeat the turtle trick here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're simply doing the query to get a date into a PHP script, then use the PHP function. In both cases, PHP and MySQL will call the system clock, mangle that time value into the formatted string, and return it. The MySQL version will have the added overhead of query parsing/compiling, and the roundtrip from PHP->MySQL->PHP. And if you're talking to MySQL via  TCP socket, you've got added overhead of building/sending/receiving a TCP connection and packets.

On the other hand, if you're using that data value within a query, you'd be better off keeping it within MySQL. For instance, by random chance, you may start a script immediately before midnight, so that PHP generates "May 24/2011 23:59:59.999" for its timestamp, but the query doesn't execute in MySQL until "May 25/2011 00:00:00.001", so now the dates don't match.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, but adding to your answer, wouldn't the user see added benefit from using PHPs `date()` in that for `SELECT` statements the database can cache queries when `CURDATE()` is not used? AFAIK using MySQL functions requires re-calculating potentially cached queries.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends.

**It's almost always faster to keep a functions result inside its native habitat.**
If you're going to use the date inside php, use the php `date()` function.

If you're going to use the date in a query use the MySQL `NOW()` function.

If php and MySQL run on different machines, **definitely** keep the data inside each machine for as long as possible. The roundtrip on the network will dwarf all other considerations.
It a good rule of thumb to strive for the minimum amount of network traffic.

Answer (score 4):

if it is an INSERT statement it's better to use the mysql built-in functions but if it's a SELECT, it faster to use the php function 'date();'.

Comment: Generally correct, but not necessarily: functions in MySQL queries are not cacheable, so for *huge* tables and *complex* queries with `WHERE somefield = CURDATE()`, it *might* be better to use the date from PHP (this has its own set of risks, see e.g. [@Marc B's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113920/faster-to-use-mysqls-curdate-or-phps-date/6114045#6114045)). Of course, this is an edge case, and you should always measure and see if there's any benefit in this.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is "in the PHP app, should I get the current date through `mysql_query('SELECT CURDATE() as today')`, or with `$curdate = date('Y-m-d')`?", then definitely use the PHP statement - the overhead for database roundtrip alone will dwarf that one call to a simple built-in PHP function (plus network latency if appserver != dbserver), that's not to mention the additional code you'll need to get the db result back (`mysql_fetch_*()` et al.).

You can try this at home ;) and measure the difference (which I would highly recommend), but IMHO `date` will be faster every time, barring some crazy convoluted scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP one is faster. Issuing a query to MySQL just to enquire as to the current date/time entails a round trip of data between PHP and the running MySQL server, which is considerably more work for the system than just PHP doing it itself.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever method causes the least communication between the two platforms will be the faster one.

If the result of the statement is to be updated or inserted into the database, use CURDATE().

If the result is to be used in PHP only, use date().