# Store timestamp using PHP:date() or MySQL:FROM_UNIXTIME()?

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

This may be trivial, but when I want to store a timestamp value (returned by, say, `time()`) into a `TIMESTAMP` column in my MySQL table, which of these two are preferable:

```
function storeTime($timestamp) {
   // Option one:
   $query = "INSERT INTO faketable (datecol) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(".$timestamp."))";
   // Option two:
   $query = "INSERT INTO faketable (datecol) VALUES (".date("YY-MM-DD HH:MM:II", $timestamp).")";
}
```

Is there even a difference?

**EDIT:** Sorry, meant `date()`, not `strtotime()`...

**EDIT 2:** `NOW()` doesn't cut the mustard, the actual timestamp is a paramater sent to my method. I don't know what it is in advance.

**EDIT 3:** I really shouldn't be asking questions at this time of night. The column in question is, in fact, a `TIMESTAMP` column, not a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: 3rd option: use mysql `NOW()`

Comment: 4th option, send `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question; No there is no logical difference. They both return  a string representation of a date https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime, which MySQL will happily convert to a DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP type. As for which is faster evidence would suggest MySQL; http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/06/23/mysql-has-functions-part-5-php-vs-mysql-performance/, [Faster to use MySQL's CURDATE() or PHP's date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113920/faster-to-use-mysqls-curdate-or-phps-date)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is a `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in mysql. That'll be a single integer->date conversion. Doing it in PHP means integerr->string->datetime, which is far less efficient.

As well, your strtotime() is completely invalid. That's not now the function works. You'd end up with's in the database.

As for storing a "now" timestamp, why not just use a timestamp field type? it automatically sets itself to the current time when you insert/update a record.

Comment: ... And about the `TIMESTAMP` column, fixed my question again... :)

Answer (score 0):

How bout

```
INSERT INTO faketable (datecol) VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
```

I think that's what you're looking for OP