# MySQL curdate() and now() vs PHP date()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, date

My query is for example this:

```
$query = "... WHERE timestamp > :thisMonday AND timestamp <= :lastMonday";
$query_params[":thisMonday"] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week'));
$query_params[":lastMonday"] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday last week'));
```

With this query I get the result from last week (starting from last week monday to last week sunday).

I've found a MySQL solution for this too but either they don't work properly (for example last monday is literally the last monday not the last week monday) or they are pretty complex for a simple task like this.

I've found this:
https://online.promoters.ro/web-design-development/mysql-curdate-and-now-vs-php-date-heavy-server-load.html
Which says to always use PHP.

And this: [Faster to use MySQL's CURDATE() or PHP's date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113920/faster-to-use-mysqls-curdate-or-phps-date)
Which says it depends. But I am not sure what the best way for my task is.

Comment: Prefer PHP date as your MySQL server and PHP doesn't have to have same time set... Also be careful about timezones.

Comment: Yes I am aware of timezones.

Comment: The result should be right. You better check the performance of different approaches with your data yourself - if performance is an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an answer, even if it may be wrong, this is just my opinion.

The first link you provided: https://online.promoters.ro/web-design-development/mysql-curdate-and-now-vs-php-date-heavy-server-load.html; I thought was completely biased and provided no proof and really said nothing to me except it caused a server problem; but I don't think he took into consideration on other data at play while he was testing, or if it could have been a different problem. There is also no date of when the article was written, so we can only guess what MySQL server version he was using.

My opinion is to keep the date format in the original language. So from Php -> MySQL -> Php. I think that might actually be the best and safest way. Another opinion is that it is easier to manipulate the time variable.